# Why are some questions highlighted?

Tags: support, questions

Recently (since today) I've noticed some of the questions are highlighted as in the picture below. What does it mean and how does it work?

[image]

Comment: It appears gmail tag is your favorite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are questions either tagged with your favourite tags or tagged with tags you are most active in.

Checking your profile I don't see any favourite tags, so it must be the latter.

Stack Exchange is trying to make a best guess as to what you might be interested in. To get more appropriate questions set up some favourite tags.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!